# Why won't the filtered results show?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

This is the code i have used to filter the average product scores

```
merged_df_no_dob['av_score_range'] = pd.cut(x=merged_df_no_dob['Av_Score'],bins=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

display(merged_df_no_dob.head())

filt = merged_df_no_dob['av_score_range'] == '(2, 3]'

merged_df_no_dob.loc[filt].head()
```

why isn't the filter showing any results from the filter i applied?

[image: The Result]

Comment: can you share `merged_df_no_dob.dtypes` ? Is `(..]` a string column ?

Comment: Oh are you saying the values in that column aren't strings? I thought this might be the case, but i'm not sure how else to filter for them results

Comment: @azro this is the type - CategoricalDtype(categories=[(1, 2], (2, 3], (3, 4], (4, 5]],
, ordered=True)

Comment: So that isn't string, and you can't compare with string. And i don't know how to deal with that